# c++ mysql++ if query is empty code never executes, but it should

Tags: c++, mysql++

If query is empty code never executes. I tried this with multiple variations. Here is simple code.

```
   mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query();
   query << "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= " 
         << mysqlpp::quote_only << username 
         << "AND password= " 
         << mysqlpp::quote_only << password;

         mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = query.store();
         mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult::const_iterator it;
         for (it = res.begin(); it != res.end(); ++it)
         {
              mysqlpp::Row row = *it;
              if (!row.empty())
              {
              // user name and password match, log them in
              std::cout << "You are logged" << std::endl;
              // rest of code goes here   
              }

              else if (row.empty())  // even just 'else' doesnt get executed
              {
              // no username or password that matches with user input
              std::cout << "Wrong username or password" <<  std::endl; 
              // rest of code goes here 
              // this never get executed, and i have no idea why
              }   
         }
```

How to check if row is empty? I tried almost anything i found in their reference manual, still nothing.

Comment: i can even use > if (row) { // log them in } but, else if (!row) it never executes.

Comment: wild guess: `res.begin() == res.end()`

Comment: Just tried it, code still doesnt get executed.

Comment: if there is no row and the iterator's begin and end are equal  it != res.end() will fail on first iteration and the loop's inner code won't e executed ... as in  `for (i = 0; i <= 0; ++i)`

Comment: facepalm. You are right, i reedited the code, and its working. Thank you johannes